# Operator # nil values at end of array

Tags: arrays, lua

I use:

```
b.x = {}
a = Obj()
a:AddParams("a", "b", "c")

...
...

function Obj:AddParams(a, b, c, d, e)
  table.insert(b.x, {["one"] = a, ["two"] = b, ["three"] = c, ["four"] = d, ["five"] = e})
end
```

and then I print #b.x and it prints 1. Shouldn't it print 2 since # operator counts nil values and I only give the first 3 parametrers on a:AddParams, leaving the last two nil? Thanks a lot

Comment: Post your exact code and result.

Answer (score 1):

#### Now that you've clarified what your code is doing:

`b.x` actually winds up being *a one element table for which the single element is another table* due to how your code calls `table.insert`:

```
b.x = {

  [1] = {                          <======= this single element in the top-level
    ["one"] = "a",                          b.x table is what the # operator counts
    ["two"] = "b",                          when you apply it as #b.x
    ["three"] = "c"
  }

}
```

Thus, calling `#b.x` will always return 1 no matter what you pass to your function, because you're always adding that *table* as a single element in the originally empty table you initialize `b.x` to be.

Note however that even if you didn't create this nested table, the value returned from `#` still wouldn't be what you're expecting. The `#` operator does *not* count nil values. What the `#` operator counts is *the length of the sequential numerical indices of a table starting at 1* (and [is not defined for tables with non-sequential numerical indices](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.6)). Thus,

- `#{ [1]="a", [2]="a" }` evaluates to  `2`
- `#{ [1]="a", [3]="a" }` is not defined by the Lua standard, because of non-sequential indices
- `#{ [1]="a", ["two"]="b" }` evaluates to `1` (because `"two"` isn't a number, it's a string).

---

#### Previous answer...

Not sure where you're getting 1 from:

```
> a = {}
> a[1] = "a"
> a[2] = "b"
> a[3] = "c"
> a[4] = nil
> a[5] = nil
> print(#a)
3
```

(Note that assigning `nil` as a value at the end of a table does nothing - you'd get the same result omitting the `a[4]` and `a[5]` lines.)

Did you perhaps actually skip `a[2]`? That would result in `#a` being 1, since it only counts contiguous items starting from index `1`.

Comment: Are you using the `...` syntax anywhere? It'd be useful to see a small self-contained reproduction of your issue.

Comment: Editted my question to the exact one :)

Comment: `"one"` and `1` are very different things for Lua table indexes.

Comment: **Nit:** Yes, `#{[1]='a', [3]='a'}` would evaluate to [`1` and not `3`](http://ideone.com/HriVXx) but the reasoning is flawed. Say we've this `{[1]='a', [2]='b', [3]='c', [5]='e'}` and although `#` would give `3` (with your reasoning) this isn't correct. [Lua manual specifically calls out](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.6) that `#` operator is defined only for sequences; thus it's undefined to use it on non-sequences, although it may seem correct at times.

Comment: `What the # operator counts is the number of continuous counting number indices starting at 1 in the table.` This isn't quite true. It returns some index `i` where `t[i] ~= nil` and `t[i+1] == nil` or possibly 0 if `t[1] == nil`. This means that it may count `nil`s in arrays with holes, or it may not.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't it print 2 since # operator counts nil values

No, exactly the opposite!

First of all, the whole notion of adding a `nil` to a table is invalid. You can store anything in a table *except* `nil`. Doing so simple deletes the value already present in that key (index) but doesn't insert a `nil` inside. It's like the mathematical null set ∅ which is used to denote emptiness as an entity but is not a tangible value/object. Accessing any index not present in the table would give you `nil`, you don't have to insert one to see them being there; any non-existent key has the value `nil` denoting that the value isn't there.

```
> a = { }
> print(a[1])
nil
> a = { "abc" }
> print(a[1])
abc
> a[1] = nil   -- this is just erasing 'abc' from the table; not add/insert nil
> print(a[1])
> nil
```

Thus they never constitute towards the size of the table.

The length operator returns, n, the count  of the elements in a sequence; a sequence is a table with values (non-nil of course - which is implied since one can never insert a nil as noted above) indexed by contiguous integers starting from 1 extending to some positive integer n. If they aren't continuous (broken with holes) then the operator `#` shouldn't be used. The [Lua manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.6) specifically calls out that using `#` is defined only if a table is a sequence. However, note that non-integer keys have no bearing on the sequence nature of the table.

Comment: Your explanation is correct but slightly misleading. Sequences must begin with the key 1. Tables that contain sequences can have additional values with non-positive integer keys, i.e., are not limited to being "arrays."

Comment: You're right; did a complete makeover to explain the concept thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

You are constructing a table and inserting it into an empty table with key 1. If you want to insert multiple elements, you have to call insert for each one.

And, the table you are constructing has string keys, which don't influence # at all.

I suggest you use an IDE with a debugger. See that [[lua]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/lua/info) tag wiki.